# MySQL crashed suddenly

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, crash

MySQL seems to crash suddenly but recovered in around 2minutes. I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 (16vcpu, 32GB RAM). I dont know what caused it.

Here is my.ini

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names = 1
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /data/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# By default we only accept connections from localhost
#bind-address   = 127.0.0.1
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
max_allowed_packet=1G
max_connect_errors=1000
max_connections=2500
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
innodb_buffer_pool_size=27G
server-id=2
log-bin=env1
expire_logs_days=2
sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
net_read_timeout=300
net_write_timeout=300
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
```

Here is my /var/log/mysql/error.log
[image]

The crash is around 8:11am as seen on the image above

Im trying to find the root cause for this. Is there any logs in Ubuntu that I can check to find more info on what caused MySQL to crash?

EDIT:
I saw the OOM (Out of Memory) error on the /var/log/syslog. Any idea what caused this?

Comment: given the lack of messages like a shutdown, it looks like it was hard killed like OOM. Check dmesg output.

Comment: @danblack It crashed again a while ago. Any idea how to fix this? or what config should I adjust

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innodb_buffer_pool_size=27G is too close to the limit especially with a large amount of (max-)connections.

Lower this down and examine utilization. `show global status like 'innodb_buffer_pool_pages%` should be full after a reasonable amount of warmup (24hrs+)

`show global status like 'innodb_buffer_pool_read%`. `read_requests` vs `reads` should be quite large. (`reads`% < 1%).

Once you have this balance hopefully there is sufficient ram available to avoid OOM, but still has sufficient performance.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try to lower my buffer pool size to 24GB. Right now read requests is around 2gb while reads is below 1mb

Comment: With those numbers I assume that `innodb_buffer_pool_reads` hasn't changed since the warmup of your data and you still have `innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free`. Also look at how many `innodb_buffer_pool_reads` occur over a minute or 2 interval. This is effectively disk reads to get data. Should be low but no point tuning to 0.

Comment: the innodb_buffer_pool_reads over 2 minute interval is around 0.9KB